# Initialize a vector inside a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have the following struct:

```
struct MsgProperties
{
    DWORD               msgSize;
    std::vector<BYTE>   vbuffer;

    //-Constructor
    MsgProperties(DWORD A = 0) : msgSize(A){}
};
```

I want to use that struct with a c++ vector so this is what I've done:

```
std::vector<MsgProperties> ReadText;
BYTE buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
DWORD bytesRead;
do
{
    bytesRead = myFile.Read(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    ReadText.push_back(MsgProperties(bytesRead, std::vector<BYTE>((BYTE*)buffer, (BYTE*)buffer + bytesRead)));

} while (bytesRead > 0);
```

but I can't figure out how to make it work correctly.  Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: You havent told us what's wrong

Comment: You're attempting to call a `MsgProperties` constructor with two arguments, but the only constructor takes either zero or one arguments.

Comment: Your constructor only takes 1 param, but you are passing it 3.

Comment: @aschepler Why do you say `zero or one`?

Comment: @FirstJens, no, 2 arguments are provided, not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need another 2 constructors:

```
MsgProperties(DWORD A, const std::vector<BYTE>& vec) : msgSize(A), vbuffer(vec) {}
MsgProperties(DWORD A, std::vector<BYTE>&& vec) : msgSize(A), vbuffer(vec) {}
```

Alernatively, a single constructor would be good too:

```
MsgProperties(DWORD A, std::vector<BYTE> vec) : msgSize(A), vbuffer(std::move(vec)) {}
```

On a side note, I do not see why you need message size at all. the size of the vector is the message size.

Comment: Very nice examples.  And thanks for the reminding me about the vector size